# What is the quickest way to find the characteristic polynomial of this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $e_k$ be the $k$-th vector of the canonical base of $\mathbb R^n$ and let $$B = [e_2 \mid e_3 \mid \dots \mid e_n \mid e_1]$$

What it the quickest way to show that the charachteristic polynomial of $B$ is $\lambda^n - 1$?

**My work**

I can show that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $B$, then $\lambda^n = 1$ (trivially because $B^n = I$)but this does not suffice as those $\lambda$ can all be equal to one; I want to show that they are distinct.

As I did not know how to do that, I resorted to use the fact (which is obvious, altough it should be proved more formally) that $tr(B^k) = 0$ for all $k < n$. Then, as the coefficients in the characteristic polynomial of $B$ (except the first and last one) are all polynomials in the variables $tr(B), tr(B^2), \dots , tr(B^{n-1})$ they are all equal to $0$.
And since $\det(B) = (-1)^{n+1}$, we have $$P_B(\lambda) = \lambda^n + (-1)^n(-1)^{n+1} = \lambda^n - 1$$

But it seems like an overkill, especially because I do not know how to prove that those coefficients are indeed polynomials in $tr(B^i)$.
Can someone suggest a more elegant way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that $I, B, B^2, \ldots, B^{n-1}$ are linearly independent (because their nonzero entries lie on entirely different diagonals). Hence no nonzero degree-$(n-1)$ polynomial over $\mathbb R$ can annilhilate $B$. In other words, $x^n-1$ is the minimal polynomial. You may continue from here.

**Edit.** On second thought, perhaps the quickest way to prove the assertion is to calculate $\det(xI−B)$ using Laplace expansion along the first row:
$$
(-1)^{1+1}x\det\pmatrix{x\\ -1&\ddots\\ &\ddots&\ddots\\ &&\ddots&\ddots\\ &&&-1&x}
+(-1)^{1+n}(-1)\det\pmatrix{-1&x\\ &-1&\ddots\\ &&\ddots&\ddots\\ &&&\ddots&x\\ &&&&-1}.
$$

Comment: thank you very much, this is great. Of course, since the minimal polynomial has degree $n$, it is also the characteristic polynomial. 
I love it. It's so elegant! Thanks again

Comment: I thought I had the answer, but I'm missing something: what is wrong in the following? You can change the basis so that $B$ becomes $I_n$. And the characteristic polynomial is invariant by change of basis (because $\det(P^{-1}(B-xI)P)=\det(P)\det(B-xI)\det(P^{-1})=\det(B-xI)$) so the CP of $B$ is the CP of $I_n$: $\pm (x-1)^n$. This is a degree $n$ polynomial but not equal to $x^n-1$.

Comment: @anderstood: You can't change basis so that $B$ becomes $I_n$. For example, $B$ moves vectors around ($e_1$ is mapped to $e_2$, etc.), which the identity tranformation doesn't...

Comment: @user1551 I though about that, but the $1$ on the last column is difficult to deal with. If can, though, please write how! I would be very grateful :)

Comment: @user1551 You can make another answer with the laplace expansion method, so one can upvote the two methods differently. To be honest though I dont think I know how to conclude from that, as those two determinants appear tough!

Comment: @Ant They are triangular matrices. The determinant of a triangular matrix is equal to the product of the diagonal entries. So we get $(-1)^{1+1}x(x^{n-1})+(-1)^{1+n}(-1)(-1)^{n-1}=x^n-1$.

Comment: @user1551 Oh gosh! I need some sleep! Thanks again :)